# publish from gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, i want to publish from a gazebo plugin. How can i do that?
In the same way as i publish from a common node? so do i have to write a main() and while{} and so on?
I want to publish torque in order to plot it with rxplot.
this is the part of the plugin:

```
torque.x = inertia.x *  controllers_.roll.update(roll_command, euler.x, angular_velocity.x, dt);
torque.y = inertia.y *  controllers_.pitch.update(pitch_command, euler.y, angular_velocity.y, dt);

body_->SetTorque(torque);
```

i try following, is this the right way?

```
ros::Publisher wrench_publisher;
geometry_msgs::Wrench moment;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins");
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
  ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
  wrench_publisher_ = node_handle.advertise<geometry_msgs::Wrench>("force", 1);
  while(ros::ok())
  {
  ros::spinOnce();
  moment.torque.x = torque.x ;
  moment.torque.y = torque.y;

  wrench_publisher.publish(moment);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30115/publish-from-gazebo/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fuerte, I just updated the plugin template if it's of any help

[gazebo_ros_template.h](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_template.h) and [gazebo_ros_template.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_template.cpp)

Similarly in electric:
[gazebo_ros_template.h](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_template.h) and
[gazebo_ros_template.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_template.cpp)

The simplest example I can think of in electric is the [sim time publisher](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_time.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot put a `main()` in a Gazebo plugin because it runs as part of Gazebo's `main()`. You'd have to put your publish functions in one of the interface methods (probably the `update()` method).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1